# cannot boot my ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot

I am running SUSE 11.2. Ubuntu is on the extended partition `/dev/sda5`, but when I boot I get

```
Error 19: Linux kernel must be loaded before initrd
```

This is the Ubuntu entry in menu.lst:

```
#Don’t change this comment – YaST2 identifier: Original name: none#
title Ubuntu 10.04
root (hd0,4)
kernel /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5 ro quiet splash
initrd /initrd.img
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your vmlinuz file is not found. It could be that this is because it is in the /boot directory on sda5, hence you should change you line to

```
title Ubuntu 10.04 root (hd0,4) kernel /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5 ro quiet splash initrd /initrd.img
```

or if it is place somewhere else, where ever its place is.

(You might need to do the same with the initrd.img file)

Also, check if the vmlinuz and initrd.img files for ubuntu have exactly this name. Usually, they have the kernel version and type in the name (i.e. vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic)

Comment: on Ubuntu there is a symlink from /vmlinuz to the actual kernel (samething for /initrd.img) so the thing to be checked is the status of those links, not /boot/vmlinuz or /boot/initrd.img

Comment: How can you do this with more than one kernel? You can only ever link to one

Comment: how do i check if the vmlinuz file is there or not I try: mount /dev/sda5 /mnt but i dont see the vmlinuz file for ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following :

```
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
cd /mnt
ls -l boot vmlinuz initrd.img
```

Check that the locations pointed to by the symlinks actually exist and are the correct files you're looking for.

For example on my box, vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-25-generic.
You can the modify your grub configuration to point to the right files as stated in txwikinger's answer.

Another quick way to debug this is to get a prompt in grub (by pressing C in grub1, not sure about grub2), then you can use tab-completion to list available files, and test it on-the-fly.